# Tinting half of my image in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon, illustration

I have created an icon, and I want to tint half of the image to make it darker.

I have created another layer ontop of the icon, so that it covers half of my icon, and decreased the transparency. How do I get that rectangle to take on the shape of the icon, instead of it remaining to be an rectangle?

Comment: You can use pathfinder options or create a clipping path: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/clipping-masks.html. There are plenty of tutorials on using a clipping mask in illustrator.

Comment: err.. you draw the shape you need.

Answer (score 3):

Start with your icon

[image: icon]

For the example I copied the circle becuase I wanted the shadow to fit inside the circle. I placed the transparent triangle on top of that circle.

[image: clipping]

Open your transparency window. Select both objects and click create mask. I also check "clip" & "invert mask"

[image: transparency]

result

[image: result]

Comment: Hmm, I tried that and when  click 'clip' the shaded layer disappears...

Comment: @Simranj then you don't want to click the `Clip` option. But you may need the `Invert` Option clicked (or not).

Comment: I tried various versions of this, and none of them seemed to work